# Use String As JSON Selector in Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a lot of values I need to extract from a JSON object called `results`.  I have stored the keys I care about in another object `myKeys`.

How can I use the values from `myKeys` as the selector in `results`?  Ultimately I want the data in `results.array1.array2.key`, `results.array1.anotherThing.key`, etc.

```
const myKeys = {
    key1: '.array1.array2.key',
    key2: '.array1.anotherThing.key',
    key3: '.array1.somethingElse.array2.key'
}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myKeys)){
    let data = {name: key, results: results[value]}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about splitting each `key` by `.` and then iteratively fetching the value? Something like this:

```js
data = {}
for (key in myKeys){
  let innerKeys = myKeys[key].split(".").shift(); // yields array ['array1', 'array2', 'key']
  let result = results
  innerKeys.forEach(key => {
    result = result[key]
  });
  data[key] = result;
}
```

This updates your local result variable to inner object through the `forEach` loop, and then in the end just set the `data[key]` to the innermost result value. The `shift()` function removes the first empty element. You can omit that if you remove the first period character.